# как вернуть null при select string_agg(concat_ws(),'; ')

Tags: sql, sql-server

`Concat_ws()` и `Concat()` в случаях когда все значения **NULL** возвращают пустую строку `''` размером varchar(1) а не `null`
Если поверх конкатинации запустить `string_agg('; ', @a)` то вместо пустой строки или null вернётся `'; ''`

```
declare @a varchar(10) = null
declare @b varchar(10) = null

select concat_ws('; ', @a , @b) as a

select
string_agg(a, ';') as agg
from(
select concat_ws('; ', cast(@a as varchar(max)),cast( @b as varchar(max))) as a
union all
select concat_ws('; ', cast(@a as varchar(max)),cast( @b as varchar(max))) as a
) as main
```

каким образом без сильной потери в производительности можно заменить пустую строку при конкатинации на null

пытался решить условием IIF(,,)

```
select
string_agg(
iif(concat_ws('; ', cast(a as varchar(max)),cast(b as varchar(max))) <> ''
,concat_ws('; ', cast(a as varchar(max)),cast(b as varchar(max))) 
,null ), ';') as agg
from @tab
```

работает, и скорость обработки запроса заметно не провисает. Может быть есть способ выполнить этот запрос быстрее или сделать код короче?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS SQL Server имеет функцию `NULLIF()` для этого.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(10) = null
    , @b VARCHAR(10) = null;

SELECT CONCAT_WS('; ', @a , @b) as a
    , NULLIF(CONCAT_WS('; ', @a , @b),'') AS Result;
```

**Результат**

```
+---+--------+
| a | Result |
+---+--------+
|   | NULL   |
+---+--------+
```

Comment: С MS SQL работаю 5й год, а вот про CONCAT_WS не знал, да и про NULLIF забыл. Благодарю за лаконичное и красивое решение)